# Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I deployed the `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network` in digitalocean ubuntu server.  I am using fabric version 2.2.

After bringing up the network, creating the channel and installing the chaincode (as per the tutorial), I downloaded the generated connection profiles `organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.json` and `organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/connection-org2.json`

In my local machine, I copied the connection profiles inside my project and changed the localhost to the ip address of the droplet server.

```
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://<some ip>:7051",

"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "https://<some ip>:7054",
```

When I enrolled the admin to CA, it is ok.  But when I submit transaction using `contract.submitTransaction(transactionName, ...args)`, I got the following error:

```
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051 timeout:3000
info: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - Unable to connect to the endorser peer0.org1.example.com due to Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Endorser- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
    ...
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  connectFailed: true
}
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Failed to connect to remote gRPC server peer0.org1.example.com url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051 timeout:3000
error: [ServiceEndpoint]: ServiceEndpoint grpcs://<some ip>:7051 reset connection failed :: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline on Discoverer- name: peer0.org1.example.com, url:grpcs://<some ip>:7051, connected:false, connectAttempted:true
error: [DiscoveryService]: send[mychannel] - no discovery results
Error initializing network:  Error: Error submitting transaction: Error: DiscoveryService has failed to return results
    ...
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Please help.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for almost the same answer...

What helped me to connect to the hyperledger test network FROM REMOTE computer (Windows 10).

1. Everytime I recreated the test network by executing:

   ./network.sh down

   ./network.sh up createChannel -ca -s couchdb

there were NEW keys generated. So I copied AGAIN them everytime to my REMOTE computer.

2. To connect I used the code from lab:

   ```
        let connectionOptions = {
            identity: identityLabel,
            wallet: wallet,
            discovery: {enabled: true, asLocalhost: false}
        };

        console.log('Connect to a Hyperledger Fabric gateway.');
        await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions);

        console.log('Use channel "mychannel".');
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');
   ```

WHAT important is: asLocalhost: false (FALSE!!!).

3. In Windows\system32\drivers\ets\hosts
   I wrote:

   192.168.2.133 orderer.example.com

   192.168.2.133 peer0.org1.example.com

   192.168.2.133 peer0.org2.example.com

where 192.168.2.133 is the IP of my hyperledger virtual machine, where is test network.

Hope I gave you some helpful ideas...